# having issue in stateprovider angularJS. Got $injector error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am facing some problem while making app with angularJS - stateProvider.

I got ***Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]***

and yes, I am working on CI framework.

Here is my code:

**index.php**

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myApp">
<head></head>
<body>
<div data-ui-view=""></div>
</body>
<script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"
></script>
<script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"
></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
"use strict";
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
     $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/home");
     $stateProvider
        .state("home", {
            url: "/home",
            templateUrl: 'home/main'
        })

});
```

Comment: During developing, use the non-minified versions. The error then will be more descriptive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vRRlVxA2VNMpRpbCqXuh?p=preview)

You have to reference `UI-Router` code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
// this is not path to UI-Router
<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>-->
<script 
    src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.15/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

*(we do not need angular-router, but UI-Router)*

[Check here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vRRlVxA2VNMpRpbCqXuh?p=preview) that your code will be working, once it gets the `UI-Router` into play